# HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, web-config

i have a trouble with my web.config when i load the page it says that error is in the string:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory     type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory,                                                                                                                                                                               EntityFramework">
```

i use Microsoft SQL server 2014
can you please help me to load the page?